# Link multiple projects together VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

We have just started tracking our work through a VSTS project that covers work across multiple projects on VSTS and thus, repositories.

Is there any way to link multiple projects to a single team project(with no repo currently linked) and then link work items to commits across these multiple projects? After having a google, the only solution I can see is to create a single team project and then have links to all of the repos.

In other words, is there any functionality for the following:
Team project 1 -> work item #1234 -> commit #1234 from Project A
Team project 1 -> work item #2345 -> commit #2345 from Project B

Apologies if this is unclear.

Comment: I am not clearly about your requirement. Do you mean multiple projects in a team project? If so, you can create multiple repositories in a team project.

Comment: So, these multiple projects are used by a host of other things, not the single team project where all of our work items are documented. It's a weird process, I know, but unfortunately I'm not PM!!

Comment: Do you mean these projects are in different team projects and you want to associate the commit to work items that just in the same team projects?